# Full Calendar Default View

Tags: css, fullcalendar, media-queries, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

Since Full Calendar is not really suitable for smaller screen I'm trying to   change the "**default view**" of the full calendar according to the width size of the screen.

I'm trying to implement that with this line code:

```
defaultView: (function () { 
  if ($(window).width() >= 768) { 
    return defaultView = 'agendaDay'; 
  } else { 
  return defaultView = 'month'; 
  } 
})
```

It's working fine however you have to refresh the browser every time to view the changes.

I tried windowResize function but no Luck. Any help would really be appreciated. Looking for sulotion without refresh the page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean you tried https://fullcalendar.io/docs/windowResize? What did you do inside that callback, exactly? Show us what you tried. Did you try to call https://fullcalendar.io/docs/changeView, perhaps? What was the result? "No luck" doesn't really give us a meaningful description of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of v5, `defaultView` was renamed to `intialView` so this works:

```
initialView: window.innerwidth >= 768 ? 'agendaDay' : 'month',
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if fullcalendar will accept a function for the defaultView optiont but your code will work if you make two adjustments:

1. Return the name of the view i.e. 'month'
2. Make your function into an IIFE

```
defaultView: (function () { 
  if ($(window).width() >= 768) { 
    return 'agendaDay'; 
  } else { 
    return 'month'; 
  } 
})()
```